# Display content in flow after height:100% sections

Tags: css, height

I'm writing a responsive web with a simple estructure, like that:
[Example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swazy/kwR5U/12/)

In `section#services` there are some subsections with `height:100%`.

But the content after (and outside) `section#services` is not displayed at the end of `section#services`. It overlaps the second subsection.

If I write `#contact` and `footer` inside `#services` the result is nice, but semantically incorrect...

I would like to understand what is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/kwR5U/14/ ?

I've added `float:left` to the services, and a `clear:both` at the end that section.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!
Still can not understand what the problem is with height:100% but the float property works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you've used two floats and then want to use them again on the next layer of div's you have to use clear:both; in your css.

A common technique is to make a html class called group, then assign .group to the html containers that have float properties.

e.g

```
<div id="container" class="group">

.group

{clear:both;}
```

Comment: Yes, I know using clear: both to return to the document flow but the problem is that at first didn´t use the float property in the containers. Don´t know what I was thinking ...

Thanks